# Processing IO values in haskell

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I'm writing a small program with IO actions in Haskell
here is

```
module StackQuestion where

import Data.Map (Map, insert, fromList)

type Name = String
type Value = String

readValue :: Name -> IO String
readValue name = do     putStrLn name
                        value <- getLine
                        return value

addPair :: Name -> Value -> Map Name Value -> Map Name Value
addPair = insert

names = map show [1..5]
values = map (\char -> [char]) ['a'..'d']
initialMap = fromList (zip names values)
```

As you can see I have some initial map with values, and function which adds a pair to map, functions which reads a value.

How I can get a clear `String` value from `readValue` and pass it to another function ?

Or should I change `type Value = String` to `type Value = IO String` and use map `Map String (IO String)` ?

And if I have `Map String (IO String)` how can i process this map, how I can get any value depening on data in `IO` containter (maybe some function `func :: (a->b) -> IO a -> b`)
For instance is there any way to compare `IO String` with the *clear* `String` ?

If I have function `func` I would have written

```
map :: Map String (IO String)
...
func (==) (map ! "key")
```

What is the strategy of working with `IO` values ?

Comment: Style: `map (\char -> [char]) ['a'..'d']` --> `map (:[])­ ['a'.­.'d']`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How I can get a clear `String` value from `readValue` and pass it to another function?

You can't; you'll have to manipulate `readValue`'s result while in the `IO` monad.

```
{- read value for name and store both in map -}
readAndStore :: Name -> Map Name Value -> IO (Map Name Value)
readAndStore name m  =  do value <- readValue name
                           return $ insert name value m
```

The `return` function takes the result of the `insert` and puts it back neatly into the `IO` monad. This code exemplifies a general pattern for manipulating values with ordinary functions inside `IO`.

> Or should I change `type Value = String` to `type Value = IO String`

No; consider what that would mean. `IO String` means a computation with possible side-effects (`IO`) with `String`-typed result. You would be mapping names to computations. (That's possible, but it's not what you mean.)

The example I've shown above uses `IO (Map Name Value)` instead; i.e., a computation in the `IO` monad with `Map`-typed result.

Comment: @Heinrich Indeed. How about adding those typical questions to the tag wiki?

Comment: So, if I have any structure of type `a` which elements are read from standard input, file etc, i need to wrap it into the `IO` monad - `somevar :: IO a` and work with this values via `liftM*` functions ?

Comment: @Max K.: I didn't dare suggest the use of `liftM` as I wasn't sure how advanced your Haskell skills are, but yes, that's the most elegant solution.